# MYSQL - How to check if a user is following another user, potentially through a subselect?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm fetching a list of activities (activities) and using a left join to grab the user data (users) who created the activity. Within my application users have the ability to follow one another.

This is my current query, which grabs all activities not posted by yourself ($user_id)

```
SELECT 
     activities.id, activities.user_id, users.id, users.name
FROM 
     activities
LEFT JOIN 
     users on activities.user_id = users.id
WHERE 
     users.id != $user_id
```

Aside from the activities + users tables, I have a another table in my application called followers:

```
followers

id | user_id_1 | user_id_2 | followed_back
 1      1           3             1       
 2      2           3             0
 3      3           1             1
```

**I need to check whether you ($user_id) have followed a particular user joined to each activity and perhaps call this new field "user_followed" which represents a true/false/null value?**

For example, I'm user_id = 1. Based on the above table, this means I have followed user_id 3. When an activity is fetched and user_id 3 is joined / responsible, the new field "user_followed" would be true.

Therefore, I think I'd need to incorporate another SELECT query, checking if the user is being followed:

```
(SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
     followers
WHERE
     user_id_1 = $user_id AND user_id_2 = users.id
)
```

I'm just largely unsure of how to incorporate this into my initial query and create a new field representing yes or no. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: your query does not make sense at all. Your example is wrong because columns 2 and 3 should have the same values, this is, according to the query you had written. The join condition is **activities.user_id = users.id**, hence columns 2 and 3 of table followers will have the same values making the initial query useless... had you even tried it before posted it here?

Comment: I'm unsure what my second query should be. I just wrote it, because by itself it checks whether a follower exists by returning a row or not. I'm asking this question because I don't know how to do it...

Comment: well your first query doesn't work. I already explained you why.

Comment: Ignoring everything else, my first query works. It returns activities and the user which created it.. I've now tried it twice...